# ggsurvplot changing confidence interval line size

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

Trying to change the line size of my confidence interval using `ggsurvplot`. When I use change the size to 1 or 2, it only affects the size of the center line, and not the size of the confidence interval lines. Any suggestions on how to alter the size of those lines?

Here is my code:

```
ggsurvplot(ovlsfit,
                  surv.scale="percent",
                  title="Survival Curve",
                  xlim=c(-0.02,5.1),
                  xlab=c("Time (y)"),
                  break.x.by=1,
                  censor=FALSE,
                  axes.offset=FALSE,
                  conf.int.style=c("step"),
                  legend=c("none"),
                  linetype = "strata",
                  color="black",
                  size=0.8,
                  risk.table=TRUE,
                  risk.table.height=0.18,
                  risk.table.pos=c("out"),
                  risk.table.fontsize=4)
```

And output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a model similar to yours for demonstration:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

ovlsfit <- survfit(Surv(time/660, status) ~ 1, data = colon)
```

Now we will try to recreate your plot:

```
p <- ggsurvplot(ovlsfit,
                surv.scale = "percent",
                title = "Survival Curve",
                xlim = c(-0.02,5.1),
                xlab = c("Time (y)"),
                break.x.by = 1,
                censor = FALSE,
                axes.offset = FALSE,
                conf.int.style = c("step"),
                legend = c("none"),
                linetype = 'strata',
                palette = "black",
                size = 0.8,
                risk.table = TRUE,
                risk.table.height = 0.18,
                risk.table.pos = c("out"),
                risk.table.fontsize = 4)

p
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no direct access to the confidence interval line size from within the call to `ggsurvplot`, but we can easily access the layers they are in and change the line size directly. Here, we will make them large for demonstration purposes:

```
p$plot$layers[[3]]$aes_params$size <- 2
p$plot$layers[[4]]$aes_params$size <- 2

p
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate it. For my future learning, how did you figure out which layer those intervals were in? I tried clicking around the object but couldn't figure out which layer applied to which aspect of the plot